# How do I change the interpolation of Nurbs curve so its Bezier?

Tags: camera, path

I'm fairly new to Blender. I know the basics and all, but I want the camera to follow a path, starting slow, speeding up, then slowing down again, but it wont let me change the interpolation, and I'm stuck on F-curves which moves at the same speed from the start to finish.
I don't know if I'm making sense, but I'm not happy and do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

**To change a Nurb to Bezier:**

Select your curve, go in *Edit* mode, and in the T panel (on the left of your 3D view) > *Tools* > press the *Set Spline Type* button and choose *Bezier*.

It looks like it doesn't work everytime so here is a way: Select your nurb in *Object* mode and convert it into a mesh with <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> > *Mesh From Curve*. Then convert this mesh again <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> *Curve from Mesh*. Now it's a Bezier. As you can see in *Edit* mode it has a lot of vertices. To simplify, activate the *Simplify Curves* addon, then select your curve in *Object* mode and <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> > *Simplify Curves*. Now in the bottom of the left panel (*T*) play with the *Distance Error* factor to reduce the amount of vertices. Once it looks good, come back in *Edit* mode to check out.

**To make an object follow a path:**

- In *Edit* mode make sure that your Bezier curve goes in the right direction, if not *W* > *Switch Direction*.
- Put your object at the center of the scene (<kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>).
- Give it a *Follow Path* constraint. Choose the curve as *Target*. Click on the *Animate Path* button of the modifier. Now the object follows the path.
- As the speed is not the one you want you need to delete the curve's self-generated animation: Select the curve, open the *Graph Editor*, on the left menu unfold the menu until you see *Evaluation Time*, select it.
- Click *N* to display the right menu, select the Modifiers tab, click X to close the *Modifiers* > *Generator*. Now your object isn't animated anymore, but you're going to fix it manually.
- Keep the curve selected. In the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Path Animation*, keep the option enabled. With *Frames* choose the number of segments that will divide the curve. With *Evaluation Time* you will decide at what segment of the curve the object will be at the moment you want on the Timeline.
- Now open your Timeline, put your cursor at frame 1, play with the *Evaluation Time* until the object is at the position you want, then insert a Keyframe on the *Evaluation Time*. Change the position of your cursor along the Timeline and repeat the operation. As you see you can move the object along the curve at the speed you want, you can even make it go backward. In the *Graph Editor* you can also change the *Interpolation* type (press T) so that the movements are more or less flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but your set spline part did not work, it said " No conversion possible." Do you how to fix this?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy way to fix that, which works every time. You need to select the Curve, go to Graph Editor, and in the panel under N in Modifiers, you will see Generator. Delete it. Then in Curve properties under Path Animation add Keyframes to the Evaluation Time with values 0 for the first frame and 100 for the last frame of the camera movement and then in Graph Editor you will see action curves with nice Bezier curves and will have all control that you need over the follow path animation.